# Output a Report from sas

Tags: sas

Hello I need to output a dat file from my sas code , something like:

```
#################################
###Game Of Thrones
################################
Number of Candidates = 1

################################
Number of Games = 3

################################
Controlppt = 1
Controlgame = 2
################################
# PPt 1 = Abc
# PPt 2 = Bcd
1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b
1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b
################################
```

So, It's a mix of comments and text and underneath is pipe delimited data.
I tried using proc export but none of the titles are printed, I also tried with Ods and using title statement for each comment, but does not work either. 
Can anyone please suggest a way to achieve this?

Comment: Please post what you've tried and indicate what output file type you're trying to achieve, text I assume? You'll need to do this semi manually using PUT statements and the REPEAT() function will likely be your friend.

Comment: Show the format of the source of the data for this report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say what your dataset looks like. So let's just invent one.

```
data have ;
  ncandidates=1; ngames=3; controlppt=1; controlgame=2;
  ppt1='Abc'; ppt2='Bcd';
  infile cards dsd dlm='|';
  input (var1-var21) ($);
cards;
1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b
1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b
;
```

Now a simple DATA step can write the report.

```
filename report 'myreport.txt';
data _null_;
  file report dsd dlm='|' ;
  set have end=eof;
  if _n_=1 then put
    32*'#'
  / '###Game Of Thrones'
  / 32*'#'
  / 'Number of Candidates = ' ncandidates
 // 32*'#'
  / 'Number of Games = ' ngames
 // 32*'#'
  / 'Controlppt = '  controlppt
  / 'Controlgame = ' controlgame
  / 32*'#'
  / '# PPt 1 = ' ppt1
  / '# PPt 2 = ' ppt2
  ;
  put var1-var21 ;
  if eof then put 32*'#';
run;
```

Comment: very simple, interesting and innovative answer.

Comment: This works thanks Tom, I tried doing this, But what if while outputing the vars in the put statement we want all of rows on the same line, pipe delimited and the line starts with a fixed text, something like: put 'input.text' va1-var21 @@; So, I get all the rows on the same line but the text "input.text' is repeated before every value for every row on the line. How can I prevent that?

Comment: Sounds like you might want to put the SET statement inside of a DO loop.  How do you get two rows in your example if all of the observations are being written to one row? Perhaps you need BY group processing?

Comment: It needs to be on one row, so my bad with the two rows, thought that'd be manageable which is why i dint put in the example. So, I need a static text and then output all the rows in one obs, how can we achieve that? Did not understand the set statement inside do loop that you've mentioned.

Comment: Just add `@@` to the end of the PUT statement that writes the data and add `/` to start of the last put that writes the follow-on line.  If you want text 'prefix' on that line then add `/ 'prefix' @` to end of the first put statement.

Comment: Doesn't work, it puts the prefix before every row. I'll post in another message what I intend to get as outcome.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty customized report. what is your output destination, a text file, or PDF?

This can be achieved with PUT statements most likely, especially if to a text file. If it's HTML or RTF it may be slightly different.

Here's a rough approximation of what you need.

```
data _null_;
file '/folders/myfolders/demo.txt';

set sashelp.class;
put 'Name';
put '###########################';
put name;

put 'Sex';
put '###########################';

put (_numeric_) ('|');
put ;*empty line;
put ;*empty line;

run;
```

Comment: Yes, I need to export to a text file . so, it'll be like a mix of these fixed text lines and then I'd have to output the contents of a dataset in the end. I had tried to use Put statements earlier but that outputs the Fixed text statements with every observation from the dataset. So, the Name, Sex statements are repeated for every observation from the input dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this :

```
data have ;
   ncandidates=1; 
   ngames=3;  controlppt=1;  controlgame=2;
   ppt1='Abc'; 
   ppt2='Bcd';
  infile cards dsd dlm='|';
  input (var1-var21) ($);
cards;
1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b
1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b
;
run;
data have1;
infile cards dsd dlm='|';
  input (var1-var2) ($);
cards;
1|2
2|3
3|4
4|5
5|6
;
run;
filename report '/home/sas/l119834/myreport.txt';
data _null_;
  file report dsd dlm='|' ;
  eof=0;
  do until(eof);
  set have end=eof;
  if _n_=1 then put
    32*'#'
  / '###Game Of Thrones'
  / 32*'#'
  / 'Number of Candidates ='  ncandidates
// 32*'#'
  / 'Number of Games = ' ngames
 // 32*'#'
  / 'Controlppt = '  controlppt
  / 'Controlgame = ' controlgame
  / 32*'#'
  / '# PPt 1 = ' ppt1
  / '# PPt 2 = ' ppt2
  / 'Input.Data='
  ;
  put var1-var21 @@;
  if eof then put / 32*'#';
  end;
  put // 83*'#'
  / '### Output Data'
  / 83* '#'
  / '# Output field name, usage = Output Area|Name'
  / '# Area = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5'
 // 'output.Name=' 
 ;
 eof1=0;
 do until(eof1);
 set have1 end=eof;
 put var1-var2 @@;
 end;

run;
```

and got this in the report:

```
################################
###Game Of Thrones
################################
Number of Candidates =1

################################
Number of Games = 3

################################
Controlppt = 1
Controlgame = 2
################################
# PPt 1 = Abc
# PPt 2 = Bcd
1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b|################################
###Game Of Thrones
################################
Number of Candidates =1

################################
Number of Games = 3

################################
Controlppt = 1
Controlgame = 2
################################
Input.Data=
# PPt 1 = Abc
# PPt 2 = Bcd
1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b
################################


###################################################################################
### Output Data
###################################################################################
# Output field name, usage = Output Area|Name
# Area = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

output.Name=
1|2|2|3|3|4|4|5|5|6
```

So, the first half is repeated twice in the output and Input.Name and the actual inputs vars are output on different lines,whereas I wanted it to be something like : `input.Data=1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b`

Comment: Fix the order of the statements in your data step. The PUT to write the top should be BEFORE the DO loop.  Similarly the PUT to write the bottom should be AFTER the DO loop.

Comment: It worked and also I simple added @ at the end of the put stetemnet when I wanted to print the next Put on the same line and it worked as well, thanks